# Update all UI when called TextView.setText()

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

When called setText(String) from thread (handler) android updated all UI widgets. (e.g. called getView in listview adapters).

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (mCurrentTime != null)
                                mCurrentTime.setText(time);
                        }
                    });
```

(used for showed current audio progress)

How update textview without updated adapters?

Comment: Is textView an item(row or item inside row) of listView?

Comment: no. TextView on activity. not in list item